# jQuery change event not firing on mobile when inside a function

Tags: android, jquery, mobile

Specifically, I'm seeing this issue on an Android tablet, but I'm told it's with ALL mobile devices -- iPhones, Nexus tablets, etc.

But I have the common problem of change events not firing. Here's the function code that has the click events assigned:

```
function do_this(with_this_data)
{
    var that = this;


    this.with_this_data = with_this_data;
    this.period = 900;
    this.updateHours();

    $('#date').change(function() {
        that.updateHours();
    });

    $('#time_hour').change(function() {
        that.updateMinutes();
    });

    // extra irrelevant data trimmed out
}
```

Now...one fix that should work is to move those .change() statements into a $(document).ready block -- but the problem is, if I do, then i get all sorts of undefined variable issues and stuff....all of the "update" functions are within said $(document).ready block and defined by names like "FutureStuff.prototype.updateMinutes."

What are my options???

Comment: One option is to put attaching of event handlers to `$(document).ready` and ask for help with those errors. It is possible that if you execute this before the document is ready, the handlers won't be set up properly. I believe it depends on when `do_this()` is executed.

Comment: Perhaps you can check whether `$('#date')` in `do_this()` matches the element? (`window.alert($('#date').length)`)

Comment: It does. But the big source of the problem is that "with_this_data" always ends up undefined if I move those .change assignments into $(document).ready, even if I actually force a value through.

Comment: And just to be clear - is the problem only on portable devices, or on desktop as well?

Comment: Only on portable devices. Works fine on desktops, all browsers -- IE8+, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and even Opera.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I don't think I can help you with it right now, but hopefully your question will receive enough attention; +1

Comment: Thank you, though; I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Mifeet, again, I appreciate your feedback; I know you weren't able to fully get me up and running, but I'm still thankful.

But anyway, I solved the issue...it meant that basically I had to rewrite a new version of the JS code and stick it in an "if this chap is using a mobile browser" block. So yeah, one huge block of code for desktop users, another for mobile...but it works. :)  And it was a pain in the hiney.

Comment: Still curious about what the problem was, though.

Comment: To be quite honest, a lot of it involved prototype functions and objects, something I'm a bit shaky with when it comes to Javascript, and I couldn't get mobile browsers to place nicely with them. So basically desktop users will get the prototype functions, and mobile users will get the old-fashioned kind that I added in. I'm sure there's a much easier solution than what I came up with, but it works. :)